# use jquery to navigate between form elements

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I'm using `backbone.js` to create a simple wizard.

In the wizard, I have 2 textboxes and a drop down and 2 buttons. The form elements are displayed one at a time, and I use `.hide()/.show()` to hide or show the element.

I want the user to be able to navigate forward and backwards, using the 2 buttons but I can't figure out how to code the `.show()/.hide()` logic in a simple and efficient manner.

Here is my simple form:

```
<div id="titleDiv" class="control">
    <label for="title">Title:</label>
    <input type="text" />
</div>

<div id="choicesDiv" class="control" style="display: none;">
    <label for="choices">Choices:</label>
    <input type="text" />
</div>

<div id="typeDiv" class="control" style="display: none;">
    <label for="types">Types:</label>
    <select name="type">
        <option>red</option>
        <option>blue</option>
        <option>green</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="directionControl">       
    <input type="button" class="prev" value="Prev" /> 
    <input type="button" class="next" value="Next" />
</div>
```

Here is the relevant js/jquery:

```
events: {
    'click .next': 'saveProceedNext',
    'click .prev': 'ProceedPrev'
},

saveProceedNext: function() {
    this.model.save();    //save before moving to the next input
    this.$('.control').hide();    //hide current
    this.$('#choicesDiv').show(); //show the next one...how to reference this without
```

Any idea?
        },

```
    ProceedPrev: function() {
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
events: {
    'click .next': 'saveProceedNext',
    'click .prev': 'ProceedPrev'
},

currentStep: 0,

saveProceedNext: function() {
    this.model.save(); //save before moving to the next input
    if (this.currentStep < 2) {
        var steps = this.$('.control');
        $(steps[this.currentStep]).hide(); // hide current
        this.currentStep++;
        $(steps[this.currentStep]).show(); // show next
    } else {
        // handle submit
    }
},

ProceedPrev: function() {
    var steps = this.$('.control');
    if (currentStep > 0) {
        $(steps[this.currentStep]).hide(); // hide current
        this.currentStep--;
        $(steps[this.currentStep]).show(); // show previous
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error: TypeError: steps[this.currentStep].hide is not a function ... not sure why though, because I'm using [] which should tell it that it's an array

Comment: I fixed my example. The TypeError was because accessing a particular index of a jQuery object removes the jQuery wrapper. Just needed to reapply the wrapper with $(steps[this.currentStep]).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".next").click(function () {
       // your save function here
       $('.control').hide();
       $('#choicesDiv').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Well that part already did work, my problem is, how to code the button logic so that the user can navigate back and forth between the 3 form elements.

Answer (score 1):

You could store a reference to the active element and cycle through its siblings with the help of [.prev( [selector ] )](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) and [.next( [selector ] )](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

Something like this, for example

```
var V = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click .next': 'saveProceedNext',
        'click .prev': 'ProceedPrev'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.active = this.$('.control').filter(':visible');
    },
    saveProceedNext: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.model.save();

        var el = this.active.next('.control');
        if (!el.length)
            el = this.$('.control:first');

        this.activate(el);
    },
    ProceedPrev: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var el = this.active.prev('.control');
        if (!el.length)
            el = this.$('.control:last');

        this.activate(el);
    },
    activate: function(el) {
        this.active.hide();
        this.active = el;
        this.active.show();
    }
});
```

Assuming your controls are surrounded by a form,

```
var v = new V({
    el: 'form'
});
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/9m3vf/